# Guardar archivos en base de datos con php

Tags: php, mysql

He estado investigando ¿Cómo guardar archivos en una base de datos mysql con php y no he encontrado nada, solo he visto que guardan los archivos en un servidor y un id en la DB y los relacionan, pero no guardan como tal el archivo ¿Es posible hacerlo? ¿Cómo?

Comment: guardar los archivos directamente en la base de datos la haría muy pesada. lo mejor es guardar el archivo en un folder y almacenar la ruta en la base

Comment: Podrías convertir el archivo a bits, pero dudo que esta sea una buen práctica. Por favor añade qué has intentado (o averiguado) hasta el momento.

Comment: Aún no he intentado nada, normalmente programo en java y efectivamente lo guardo como un arreglo de bits, en todo caso, creo que optaré por almacenar los archivos en un folder tal como sugieres, @MauricioAriasOlave

Comment: Crea un campo de tipo blob, puede almacenar archivos de distintos tipos. Dentro del campo lo insertas, deberás usar fopen() y fread(). Un ejemplo claro lo puedes encontrar en [este link](http://programacion.net/articulo/manejo_de_datos_blob_con_php_y_mysql_194).
De todas formas no es una buena práctica almacenar archivos dentro de la db ya que en una migración demoraría horas, días o más dependiendo del peso de la misma.